# AngularJs Watch (childscope) Call Member Function

Tags: angularjs

My directive is inside a ng-if, so it creates is own child scope. If I console.log $scope in the watch function it seems to be the parent element. But in Angular you can't access childscopes from the parent. IF I do remove the $parent in the HTML the watch function does not work anymore. The directive does not have a possibility to use ng-change. How can I see if a change happened and then call the `filterWithOptions` function.

JS

```
angular.module("blub").controller('TagCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, filterService, optionsService) {
  var self;
  self = this;
  $scope.min = 0;
  $scope.max = 10;
  this.filterOptions = function() {
    return optionsService.getToggleStatus('erweiterteSuchoptionen');
  };
  this.filterWithOptions = function(self) {
    console.log("Filter with options", $scope.min, $scope.max);
    filterService.setMinMax($scope.min, $scope.max);
    return self.filter();
  };
  this.filter = function() {
    console.log("Filter");
    filterService.setIncludeTags($scope.tagsInclude);
    filterService.setExcludeTags($scope.tagsExclude);
    $scope.filtered = filterService.filter();
    $scope.number = $scope.filtered.length;
    $rootScope.$broadcast('FILTERED');
  };
  $scope.$watch('min', function() {
    return console.log($scope);//works
  });
  //$scope.$watch('min', ???); //What to put in here
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-if="tagController.filterOptions()" class="filter-options">
   <h2>Anzahl(Minimal - Maximal)</h2>
   <div range-slider min="0" max="10" model-min="$parent.min" model-max="$parent.max"  show-values="true"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `range-slider` a directive you own, or is it part of a 3rd party lib? If you own the code, you should look into modifying your directive scope bindings. This [article](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html) explains the differences between `=` (bi-directional), `&` (parent execution), and `@` (local) scope bindings.

Comment: https://github.com/danielcrisp/angular-rangeslider
Third party I could fork it.